# ASUS VivoBook W202na : Will it run

Tags: laptop, release-juno, asus

Am interest installing the Juno. Just want to make sure it will run smoothly on this laptop or not. I have the VivoBook W202na. Changing over from Windows 10 because of poor performance.

"Display
11.6" HD (1366*768), matte

Processor
Intel® Dual-Core Celeron N3350 1.1GHz (Turbo up to 2.4GHz)

Graphics
Intel HD

Memory
4GB LPDDR3 (On Board)

Storage
64GB EMMC"
- Source: https://store.asus.com/us/item/201804AM060000009/-ASUS-VivoBook-W202NA-YS03-Rugged-11.6-inch-K-12-Education-Laptop,-Intel%C2%AE-processor-,-4GB-Ram,-64GB-emmc-flash-storage,-spill-proof-keyboard,-Windows-10-S

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I just got a similar model, the Vivobook E203MA. I'm running Elementary OS on that and loving it. It runs so much better than Windows did in the little time I used it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing on your list that does not meet [elementarys recommended system specifications](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) is the Intel Celeron Dual-Core Processor. You're base-clock is relatively low and you get no hyper-threading, so no pretending to be a quad core when you need it. That said the turbo is not that bad.

elementary OS won't make this computer a powerhouse, but it should run relatively okay. Don't take performance you see off a USB test as representative. I can't comment on whether or not you will encounter any driver issues, specifically with Wi-Fi.